# Iterate variable name inside loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, turtle-graphics

I have little practice experience with programming, but I have started to learn python and would like to create a function for counting the most frequent words in a text. Now, I'm sure that my version is not the best way to do it, but it works:

```
 import os

 punctuation = "~!@#$%^&*()_-=+[{]}\\|'\";:,<.>/?"

 def remove_punctuation(text):

     text_wo_punctuation = ""
     for word in text:
         if word not in punctuation:
             text_wo_punctuation += word
     return text_wo_punctuation

 with open(r'New Text Document.txt') as f:

     text = f.read().lower()
     t = remove_punctuation(text).split()
     dictionary = {}
     for word in t:
         if word in dictionary:
             dictionary[word] = dictionary[word] + 1
         else:
             dictionary[word] = 1

 print(dictionary)

 def top_five(d):

     top = {}
     value1 = 0
     value2 = 0
     value3 = 0
     value4 = 0
     value5 = 0


     for key in dictionary:
         if value1 < dictionary[key] and key not in top:
             value1 = dictionary[key]
             top1 = {key:value1}
         else:
             continue
     top.update(top1)    
     for key in dictionary:
         if value2 < dictionary[key] and key not in top:
             value2 = dictionary[key]
             top2 = {key:value2}
         else:
             continue
     top.update(top2)
     for key in dictionary:
         if value3 < dictionary[key] and key not in top:
             value3 = dictionary[key]
             top3 = {key:value3}
         else:
             continue
     top.update(top3)
     for key in dictionary:
         if value4 < dictionary[key] and key not in top:
             value4 = dictionary[key]
             top4 = {key:value4}
         else:
             continue
     top.update(top4)
     for key in dictionary:
         if value5 < dictionary[key] and key not in top:
             value5 = dictionary[key]
             top5 = {key:value4}
         else:
             continue
     top.update(top5)
    return top

 print(top_five(dictionary))
```

The above code will give the following output:

> {'word1': "freq1", 'word2': "freq2", 'word3': "freq3", 'word4': "freq4", 'word5': "freq5"}

Although this is the result I want, I have tried to simplify my function and let the user choose how many words it should count the frequency for:

```
 def top_five(d,n):

     top = {}
     values = {}
     for i in range(1,n+1):
         values["value"+str(i)]=0
     for i in range(1,n+1):
         top["top"+str(i)]=0

     for i in range(1,n+1):
         for key in dictionary :
             if values["value"+str(i)] < dictionary[key] and key not in top:
                 values["value"+str(i)] = dictionary[key]
                 top["top"+str(i)] = {key:values["value"+str(i)]}
             else:
                 continue
         top.update(top1)
     print(top)
     return top
```

This code will create a dictionary with value1, value2 etc. that I could use in my loop and another dictionary with top1, top2 etc., but it will not work because "and key not in top" will not work.

```
top["top"+str(i)] = {key:values["value"+str(i)]}
```

this will create a dictionary within a dictionary. I am stuck at this, as I couldn't find a way to make the "top" dictionary useful, or iterate a variable name within a loop. I have read that lists or dictionaries should be used and that variable name iteration is not a good idea, but I didn't understand why that is and I can't think of a way to make lists or dictionaries useful in my for loop.

As I said, I know that it may not be the best approach at making this kind of function, but my question is: how can I simplify the one I already made and get the loop working?

Thanks!

Comment: In future, please format code using the `{}` toolbar button rather than as a quote. If you inspect the edits to your question, you will see what I mean. Either way, good job for asking a complete question with expected results, attempted code, and all the other elements.

Comment: A better way would be to create a list of `(word, frequency)` tuples, sort this by frequency, then take the first N elements of the list.

Comment: Cant you just use `collections.Counter` ? you may endup with a one liner as the following `sorted(Counter(my_str.split()))[:N]`

Comment: Mad Physicist: thanks, I will remember that.
                                                                                                                       
Elbehery: I could use that, but I wanted to make my own function with blackjack and hookers, just to exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding you want to implement your own bubble sort, instead of using Python's quick sort, and you want to count words yourself, instead of using Counter, let's tighten up your code to take advantage of Python idioms and lighten the load a bit on your poor tortoise:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from collections import defaultdict

PUNCTUATION = "~`!@#$%^&*()_-=+[{]}\\|'\";:,<.>/?"

def remove_punctuation(text):
    """ Removes punctuation characters from given text """

    text_wo_punctuation = ""

    for letter in text:
        if letter not in PUNCTUATION:
            text_wo_punctuation += letter

    return text_wo_punctuation

def count_words(filename):
    """ Returns a dictionary of words and word count from "file" """

    dictionary = defaultdict(int)  # if you won't use Counter, at least use defaultdict()

    with open(filename) as file:
        text = remove_punctuation(file.read()).lower().split()

        for word in text:
            dictionary[word] += 1

    return dictionary

def dict_sort(d, reverse=False):
    """
    Sort given dictionary "d" values (& keys) in ascending (default)
    or descending (reverse = True) order
    Outputs tuple of: list of keys, list of values
    Recommended format for output: k, v = dict_sort(d)
    """

    key_list = list(d.keys())
    value_list = list(d.values())

    for _ in range(len(value_list) - 1):
        for i in range(len(value_list) - 1):
            if reverse:
                if value_list[i] > value_list[i+1]:
                    value_list[i], value_list[i+1] = value_list[i+1], value_list[i]
                    key_list[i], key_list[i+1] = key_list[i+1], key_list[i]
            else:
                if value_list[i] < value_list[i+1]:
                    value_list[i], value_list[i+1] = value_list[i+1], value_list[i]
                    key_list[i], key_list[i+1] = key_list[i+1], key_list[i]

    return key_list, value_list

def word_freq():
    """ Input how many words to plot on graph """

    while True:
        try:
            n_freq = int(input("How many of the most frequent words would you like to display?\n"))

            if not 1 <= n_freq <= 10:
                print("Please input an integer between 1 and 10:")
                continue

        except ValueError:
            print("Please input an integer between 1 and 10:")
            continue
        else:
            break

    return n_freq

def graph_word_freq(n, f, w):
    """
    Draw bar chart of most frequent words in text
    n: number of words to plot (between 1 and 10)
    f: word frequency list
    w: word list
    """

    window = Screen()
    window.bgcolor("honeydew")
    window.title("Most Frequent Words")

    if f[0] < 960:
        width = 60
        spacing = 20
        y = 500
        y_pos = -480
        x_pos = - (30 + 40 * (n - 1))
    else:
        width = 100
        spacing = 40
        y = f[0] / 2 + 20
        y_pos = -f[0] / 2
        x_pos = - (50 + 70 * (n - 1))

    window.setworldcoordinates(-y, -y, y, y)
    tortoise = Turtle(visible=False)
    tortoise.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

    tortoise.penup()
    tortoise.setposition(x_pos, y_pos)

    for i in range(n):
        if f[i] < (f[0] - f[n]) / 3:
            tortoise.color("SeaGreen", "ForestGreen")
        elif (f[0] - f[n]) / 3 <= f[i] < (f[0] - f[n]) / 1.5:
            tortoise.color("orange", "gold")
        else:
            tortoise.color("coral3", "IndianRed")

        tortoise.left(90)

        tortoise.begin_fill()

        tortoise.forward(f[i])
        tortoise.right(90)

        tortoise.forward(1/2 * width)
        tortoise.write(f[i], align='center')
        tortoise.forward(1/2 * width)

        tortoise.right(90)
        tortoise.forward(f[i])

        tortoise.end_fill()

        tortoise.forward(20)
        tortoise.right(90)

        tortoise.forward(1/2 * width)
        tortoise.write(w[i], align='center')
        tortoise.backward(1/2 * width)

        tortoise.right(90)
        tortoise.forward(20)
        tortoise.right(90)
        tortoise.forward(spacing)

    window.exitonclick()

dictionary = count_words("New Text Document.txt")

words, values = dict_sort(dictionary, reverse=True)

n_freq = word_freq()

graph_word_freq(n_freq, values, words)
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed now that I left some unnecessary stuff in the graph drawing function. It was initially made separately, for random data, but you're right, a word frequency sequence can never be negative so no need for some of the stuff there. Also, I didn't know that the respective algorithm has a name, I will look more into sorting algorithms. The way you modified the function, though, needs to have False in words, values = dict_sort(dictionary, reverse=True). If you edited my code without even running it, you did a great job!

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my code as per Barmar's recommendation:

```
def remove_punctuation(text):
""""Removes punctuation characters from given text"""
punctuation = "~`!@#$%^&*()_-=+[{]}\\|'\";:,<.>/?"
text_wo_punctuation = ""
for word in text:
    if word not in punctuation:
        text_wo_punctuation += word
return text_wo_punctuation

def count_words(file):
    """Returns a dictionary of words and word count from "file" """
    with open(file) as f:
        text = remove_punctuation(f.read()).lower().split()
        dictionary = {}
        for word in text:
    #        print(word)
            if word in dictionary:
                dictionary[word] = dictionary[word] + 1
    #            print("**Existing**")
            else:
                dictionary[word] = 1
    #            print("**New**")
    #        print(dictionary[word])
    return dictionary
    #print(dictionary)

def dict_sort(d, reverse = False):
    """Sort given dictionary "d" in ascending (default)
        or descending (reverse = True) order
        Outputs tuple of: list of keys, list of values and dictionary
        Recommended format for output: a,b,c = dict_sort(d)"""
    key_list = []
    value_list = []
    for key in d:
        key_list.append(key)
        value_list.append(d[key])
    #print(key_list)
    #print(value_list)
    for i in range(len(value_list)-1):
        for i in range(len(value_list)-1):
            if reverse == False:
                if value_list[i] > value_list[i+1]:
                    value_list[i],value_list[i+1] = value_list[i+1],value_list[i]
                    key_list[i],key_list[i+1] = key_list[i+1],key_list[i]
            elif reverse == True:
                if value_list[i] < value_list[i+1]:
                    value_list[i],value_list[i+1] = value_list[i+1],value_list[i]
                    key_list[i],key_list[i+1] = key_list[i+1],key_list[i]
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(value_list)):
        d[key_list[i]] = value_list[i]
    sorted_dict = d    
    return key_list,value_list,sorted_dict

def word_freq():
    """Input how many words to plot on graph"""
    while True:
        try:
            n_freq = int(input("How many of the most frequent words would you like to display?\n"))
            if (n_freq < 1 or n_freq > 10):
                print("Please input an integer between 1 and 10:")
                continue
        except(ValueError):
            print("Please input an integer between 1 and 10:")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return n_freq

def graph_word_freq(n,f,w):                     #create function to draw chart
    """Draw bar chart of most frequent words in text
        n: number of words to plot (between 1 and 10)
        f: word frequency list
        w: word list"""

    import turtle                                       #import turtle module
    window = turtle.Screen()                            #create screen
    window.bgcolor("honeydew")                          #define screen color
    window.title("Most Frequent Words")                 #set window title
    if f[0] < 960:
        y = 500
        y_pos = -480
        width = 60
        spacing = 20
        x_pos = -(30+40*(n-1))
    else:
        width = 100
        spacing = 40
        y = f[0]/2+20
        y_pos = -f[0]/2
        x_pos = -(50+70*(n-1))

    #turtle.screensize(y,y)                              #set window size
    turtle.setworldcoordinates(-y,-y,y,y)
    tortoise = turtle.Turtle()                          #create turtle
    tortoise.hideturtle()                               #hide turtle stamp
    tortoise.penup()                                    #raise turtle pen
    tortoise.setposition(x_pos,y_pos)                   #position turtle
    tortoise.pendown()                                  #put turtle pen down
    tortoise.speed(5)                                   #set drawing speed

    for i in range(n):
        if abs(f[i]) < ((f[0]-f[n])/3):
            tortoise.color("SeaGreen","ForestGreen")    #set turtle color
        elif abs(f[i]) >= ((f[0]-f[n])/3) and abs(f[i]) < ((f[0]-f[n])/1.5):
            tortoise.color("orange","gold")             #set turtle color
        else:
            tortoise.color("coral3","IndianRed")        #set turtle color

        tortoise.begin_fill()                           #begin drawing shapes
        tortoise.left(90)
        tortoise.forward(f[i])                          #draw bar height
        tortoise.right(90)
        tortoise.forward(1/3*width)                            #prepare for text
        if f[i] >= 0:
            tortoise.write(f[i])                        #write value
        else:
            tortoise.penup()
            tortoise.right(90)
            tortoise.forward(15)
            tortoise.write(f[i])
            tortoise.forward(-15)
            tortoise.left(90)
            tortoise.pendown()
        tortoise.forward(2/3*width)                     #bar width
        tortoise.right(90)
        tortoise.forward(f[i])
        tortoise.left(90)
        tortoise.penup()
        tortoise.right(90)
        tortoise.forward(25)
        tortoise.left(90)
        tortoise.forward(-2/3*width)
        tortoise.write(w[i])                            #write word
        tortoise.forward(2/3*width)
        tortoise.left(90)
        tortoise.forward(25)
        tortoise.right(90)
        tortoise.forward(spacing)                       #spacing
        tortoise.pendown()
        tortoise.end_fill()                             #stop drawing shapes
    turtle.exitonclick()

dictionary = count_words("New Text Document.txt")

words,values,dictionary = dict_sort(dictionary, reverse = True)

n_freq = word_freq()

graph_word_freq(n_freq,values,words)
```

It now works as intended. Thanks, mate!